# Regex Java "test 123" needs to fail

Tags: java, regex, letters-and-numbers

So I created a program that would bring go through an input file and only pull the lines with 2 words in them. I then am trying to pull only the lines with ONLY letters. If there is any number I need it to fail. So far after researching I have come up with the code below and am just stuck on how else to get "test 123" to fail. It keeps passing.`Below is the call for my match function and the function itself.
           *
           *

```
else if (line.matches("[\\w\\-.]{2,} [\\w\\-.]{2,}"))
        {
            getmatch();
        } 




public static String getMatch() 
    {
        if (line.matches("/[a-zA-Z]+/g") )
        {
            match=line;
        }

        return match;
    }
```

Comment: if you want to match with line that has only two words like only letters and spaces. then you have to strictly use beginning and ending symbol in your regex. like `"^\s*[A-Za-z]+\s+[A-Za-z]+\s*$"`

Comment: @varatharajan Not true in the case of `String#matches`, which always uses those anchors implicitly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Okay. good to know that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following general pattern to match lines with two letter-only words:

```
\s*[A-Za-z]+\s+[A-Za-z]+\s*
```

This pattern will also take into account any amount of whitespace on either side of the two words, or in between them.  Note that `String#matches` by default includes starting and ending anchors around the input regex pattern, so we don't need to explicitly include them, though I did include them in the demo below.

You would use this pattern as:

```
String input = " Hello World  ";
if (input.matches("\\s*[A-Za-z]+\\s+[A-Za-z]+\\s*")) {
    System.out.println("Found a match!");
}
```

### Demo